# Can I make more than one Tournesol?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

*"The Sunflower—A single, beautiful sunflower. Brilliant as the sun, wondrous as creation."*

This is how the bazaar on Rabanastre describes Tournesol, an incredibly hard-to-build sword, due to it's big amount of ingredients on the recipe.

I've played over 600 hours of FFXII and I never figured if it is possible to get more than one of it. Does anyone knows? This also applies to other itens that need recipes

Also, sorry for the poor english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a [post from Gamefaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/459841-final-fantasy-xii/answers/280463-can-i-have-2-tournesols) explains when googling *FF12 multiple tournesol*:

> Only a few Bazaar Goods are repeatable, namely X-Potion packs, rare metals, and the like. Equipment and ammo are a no-go, unfortunately. So, no, you cannot get more than one Tournesol. There are items that can be found, earned, and purchased from Bazaar, however. These include Masamune (Hunt and Bazaar), Ultima Blade (Pharos and Bazaar) and Stoneblade (Great Crystal and Bazaar), among a few others.

Comment: Oldish question, but fun fact. You can actually get another [Tournesol](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Tournesol_(Final_Fantasy_XII)) in the Zodiac Age version by stealing it from one of the trail mode stage 100 bosses, but items obtain in the final stage unfortunately can't be migrated into the main game